# Started fullstackopen for the first time and getting a "favicon.ico" request in the network tab

Tags: frontend, favicon, web-development-server, react-fullstack

So I basically started this web dev course by fullstackopen and in one of the steps it says that once you open the Developer Console, and refresh the tab, 2 requests shall appear (one HTTP GET request and the another for an image to be retrieved from the server, but whenever I refresh I get this unknown request called "favicon.ico" every time. For the next steps also the same is happening. While the courses explains all the other requests made, it does not even talk about this one because this does not appear in their examples. So I just wanted to know why I am getting this random request. [first one is what the network tab should have displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQdYz.png)

[second image shows what I get when I follow the instructions of the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1XZb.png)

Comment: I suggest reading [minimal reproducible cod](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then updating your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akki mentioned, this is the icon you would see on a tab in the browser. Like the StackOverflow icon for this page.

You are getting a status 200 response, so it does find it in your root

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will show an icon to the left of the URL. This known as the `favicon.ico` and is typically fetched from `website.com/favicon.ico`. Your browser will automatically request it when browsing to different sites. If your browser receives a valid `favicon.ico` file, it will display this icon. If it fails, it will not display a special icon.

In either circumstances, browsing is not affected.

It would seem that you don't have a favicon in your root directory of the project thus the `unknown request`